# How to interprete paypal billing agreement creation?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am building a paypal subscription system but i have some difficulties to understand some points. When using sandbox i can't simulate a payment denial process so when the payment is made, paypal redirect me to my "approval url callback" and a billing agreement is created.

So i want to know , in a real situation, will paypal redirect me to the approval url and create this billing agreement even if the payment didn't occur yet ? or this one can be created if and only if the payment is accepted ? (So if paypal denied the payment the billing agreement will never be created)

In my case, my customers will need to access to some paid features of my website so, should i wait for the "ipn webhook notification (PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED)" which can take several minutes to be fired to my endpoint, or can i grant access immediately after the billing agreement is created ?

Which is the most secure thing to do ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the user cancels the checkout, Paypal will redirect to your cancel URL.
But the failed payment cases are not clear to me either. I believe that the agreement will be created even if the payment fails, since it needs to exist for the payment attempt to be done, but I don't work at Paypal :).

My approach is to activate the subscription on a successful redirect no matter what, [edit: the execute response returns an `agreement_details.next_billing_date` in the past, so you can't use that] with a short initial subscription expiration (4h). When our webhook receives a `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` message, we fetch the agreement billing agreement details, and update the subscription expiration to the new `agreement_details.next_billing_date`. But if the webhook receives a `PAYMENT.SALE.DENIED`, we just let the subscription expire.

HTH.